# How to create a map from a comprehension?

Tags: elixir

I tried

```
units = %{}
for s <- squares, u <- unitlist, s in u, do: Map.put(units, s, u)
```

which doesn't seem to work. I would like to create a map where the keys are in squares the values are in unitlist and the map should only contains those squares which are in the unitlist.

Ultimately, I'd like something like

```
units = for s <- squares, u <- unitlist, s in u, ????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which works

That code will not work like you probably expect it to. What it does is create a new Map on every iteration, but the `units` map declared before will not be modified because variables in Elixir are immutable.

You can use the `into` option with `for` to create a map. For that, the body of the loop must return a 2-tuple of the key and value.

```
units = for s <- squares, u <- unitlist, s in u, into: %{}, do: {s, u}
```

Comment: I looked at `into: %{}` but I couldn't quite understand how it works. My understanding was that `for` executes the things separated with commas in the order they are listed but apparently `into: %{}`  runs after `do: {s, u}` and directs the result to be inserted into a map?

Comment: Ha. I was only just reading about `into: %{}` in this excellent [cheatsheet](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/elixir). Thought I was going to get the chance to answer my first Elixir question for a minute... :D

Comment: @chx `into` and `do` are normal keyword arguments to the macro `for`. It doesn't matter what order they appear in if you're using the `do:` syntax. If you're using a `do ... end` block syntax, it obviously needs to be before the `do` because putting it after is a syntax error.